# Google Android Project галочка

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-android

Зачем эта галочка при билде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что она изменит в проекте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Согласно документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html) в этом случае вместо сборки apk файла Unity выдаст вам проект для Android Studio, который можно будет собрать уже в ней.

Comment: а есть ли разница где собирать, прямо из юнити или из Android Studio?

Comment: @k0vpack, ну, какая-то определённо есть) раз такая опция доступна. Но, если вы её не знаете, то, видимо, вам это и не нужно - собирайте из юнити и не заморачивайтесь :)

Comment: вот по этому и спросил, вдруг чего не знаю что может мне помочь.